# XRD with random orientation

Tags: x-ray-crystallography

How can XRD examine a randomly oriented crystal lattice. Doesn't it needs a tidy structure? Why does the diffractogram always show the same image even when we change the sample(the sample shoulder hasil the difference lattice orientation)

Comment: When the X-rays scatter from an atom, they scatter spherically (i.e. in all directions). So why do you think the result *should* depend on crystal orientation?

Comment: "Diffractogram" belong to the vocabulary of powder crystallography. Is it what you are doing? Diffracting X-rays on a powder?

Comment: Yes Bourhis. Search or on Google. They use powder as sample. And i think the orientation will matter

Comment: Why would diffraction from a large number of randomly ordered grains show directionality? That randomness is at the heart of powder diffraction techniques.